# How to get rid of flicker during scrolling for artificially fixed elements?

Tags: javascript, css

This is a very simple example of sticking an element at the top of another element's visible area. When `.container` is scrolled, `.fixed` stays at the top.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="fixed">fixed content</div>
    <div class="content">regular content<br/>regular content<br/>regular content<br/>regular content<br/>regular content</div>
</div>

<style type="text/css">
.container {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
}
.content {
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
}
.fixed {
    position: absolute;
    width: 500px;
    margin-top: 2rem;
    border 1px solid red;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.container').scroll(function () {
        var top = $('.container').prop('scrollTop');
        console.log(top);
        $('.fixed').css('top', top);
    });
</script>
```

The problem with this is that if the browser is not fast enough, the `.fixed` element flickers when I scroll. It lags behind the scroll (compare the position of the text in `.fixed` to the text in `.content` as you're scrolling). On my desktop it works flawlessly, but when I try running this in Chromium in a virtual machine, I can see the flicker.

Is there any other way to catch the scroll event and set the position of my `.fixed` element before the browser renders the page?

**edit** Updated example to include horizontal scrolling. The fixed element should only be fixed vertically.

Comment: This is a bit of the actual page. Due to the actual layout of the page (which is much more complex), I cannot use `position:fixed`. This is the smallest bit of code I could do to reproduce the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Use a double container:

```
<div class="container-wrapper">
    <div class="fixed">fixed content</div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="content">regular content<br/>regular content<br/>regular content<br/>regular content<br/>regular content</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

With the CSS:

```
.container-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
}
.container {
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.content {
    height: 500px;
}
.fixed {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 245px;
    border 1px solid red;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

This way you won't need jQuery to reposition the `.fixed` div when you scroll, and it won't flicker.

**EDIT** To address the horizontal scrolling...

```
$('.container').on('scroll', function() {
    var left = this.scrollLeft;
    $('.fixed').css('left', -left + 'px');
});
```

This should move the `.fixed` div without flickering. In your solution, the flickering was caused because the browser moved your div while scrolling, and the event handler then moved it again. Now it will only move once.

Comment: My example is incomplete. I have horizontal scrolling and I need the fixed content to actually be fixed vertically (as in my example) and scroll vertically. I will update it now.

Comment: Edited my solution to include a bit of jQuery to move the object when you scroll horizontally